# convert list into parent class list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class Base {}
public class Derived : Base {}

public List<Derived> derivedList = new List<Derived>();

public List<Base> baseList = derivedList as List<Base>;
```

derivedList is unable to be cast back into a list of the parent class.

is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net this is not allowed by design. The reason is that `List<T>` is ***in-variant***, not ***co-variant***. You could change `List` to `IEnumerable` and it will work:

```
public IEnumerable<Base> baseList = derivedList as IEnumerable<Base>;
```

But, if you want to add new items to `baseList`, then you can go with the other answer by @K N.

---

*P.S*: For additional details you can read the articles about *Covariance* and *Contravariance*. (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

And especially, I recommend you these two videos by Eric Lippert:

[First Part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6D8YDSvpEYI)
[Second Part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VtfiQ10PWY)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Base> baseList = derivedList.Cast<Base>().ToList();
```